# how to hide title bar in xamarin forms in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin

I want to hide title bar in Xamarin forms in WPF using fresh MVVM.I Want to show my player page on full screen mode without any border and also hide minimize maximize and close buttons

I have used property Window size None and allow Transparency false. But it hides only  minimize maximize and close buttons not whole title bar

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about what exactly your issue is, so please provide some screenshot or code snippet.
But I think the answer you are looking for is (in xaml)

```
(in the Window tag) WindowStyle="None"
```

Edit: This will hide the titlebar and any standard window buttons (for example the 'close', 'minimize' and 'hide' buttons)

Comment: But next time you ask a question, please look at this post: [stackoverflow's guide on questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)